# Windows apachePHP exec zip command does not finish

Tags: php, windows, apache, zip, wamp

We have an interesting problem with windows server running WAMP (apache, mysql, php).
Basicly we have an application that packs a folder into a zip file that users can download. Contents of the zip file vary and have to be prepared dynamically according to user's wishes.

We use this command to zip files together. (We also tried using winrar, but it had the same problem)
exec('c:\Windows\system32\7za a -mx0 -tzip "'.$zipPath.'" "'.$zipDirPath.'"', $output, $return_var );

Problem is that sometimes this commands does not finish.
It successfully creates the zip file, but doesn't finish and seems it keeps running. (Does not happen, if same command is entered through the command line)

If anyone has any ideas how to solve this problem, please help :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the same PHP [ZipArchive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) class, there you will find the doc for it.

Comment: We have very large files (may be over 2GB that will be zipped). So using PHP class is not a good idea, as it will run very slowly. Or am I wrong?

Comment: When making a system call from PHP it matters! but when you use the same process (PHP) it's better, so using the ZipArchive class will be the best idea for you and even faster you'll notice that.